# What do I set ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME to?

Tags: android

I'm on a CentOS 6.3 machine.  I installed both ant and openjdk via yum.  What should I set the environment variable ANT_HOME (and JAVA_HOME) to?  I looked thru the entire filesystem and could not find anything tha looked right for ant.

For java, there's lots of symbolic links in /usr/lib/jvm.  And 'java' is actually a symbolic link, that points to another link, and another, which eventually points to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java, which is an actual file.  What should I set JAVA_HOME to?

Finally, I'm asking because I'm trying to build some simple Android programs book 'Beginning Android 4' and got this error message:

```
# ant debug
 Buildfile: build.xml

 BUILD FAILED
      NowRedux/build.xml:49: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found
```

From other WWW searches, it seems the above can be caused by not having ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME set, which I don't.

Answer (score 5):

```
export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
```

I dont' use CentOS, but I looked in the RPM package "files" section (yum is an RPM frontend/wrapper of sorts, if I recall). http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/6.3/i386/Packages/ant-1.7.1-13.el6.i686.html

Also, I'd stick to the packages if you can, but for simple Java stuff you can also just download the ant dist and Java dist and unpack them somewhere on your own (say /opt) and then use those dirs the non-package way.

Once you've set the variables you can make sure they exist with echo $JAVA_HOME and echo $ANT_HOME and so on.

LASTLY, you might want to post this on ServerFault, that seems like it might be more appropriate and you might get better Linux/Package related responses (I answered anyway, in case it helps, but again, I'm not a CentOS guy, and haven't used YUM/RPM in a long time, so grain of salt and all).

Comment: I downloaded ant and java and manually installed them and set ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME manually.  However, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

> For java, there's lots of symbolic links in /usr/lib/jvm. And 'java' is actually a symbolic link, that points to another link, and another, which eventually points to /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java, which is an actual file. What should I set JAVA_HOME to?

To something you perhaps do not already have.

In theory, you would have it point to `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk` in this case, the Java directory that is the home of the `java` program that you will be using.

However:

- That is a JRE, not a JDK
- The Android SDK does not formally support Java 7 -- the system requirements are for JDK 6

Hence, I recommend downloading JDK 6 (or the equivalent OpenJDK), installing it, and setting up `JAVA_HOME` to point to its equivalent directory (probably a peer of `usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk`). You may also need to run the appropriate CentOS command to switch those symlinks to `java` to point to the one from your JDK. I do not use CentOS, so I cannot tell you what those are, but there should be some "update alternatives" command to run.

Comment: Okay, I Installed Java 6, and added them to my path before the others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was the correct way to solve the problem, or it merely sidesteps it, but I did this

```
rm MyProjects/NowRedux/build.xml
android update project --target 8 --path MyProjects/NowRedux
```

And it worked. It basically creates a new build.xml file that doesn't refer to com.android.ant.SetupTask (so, that problem might still be broken, but at least I found a workaround)